# Laravel retrieving records with eager loading - return blank

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I am currently creating a function to generate a report. As of now the parent table has ~17k records and it will grow.

Unfortunately, everytime I run the query it just return empty/blank result

```
$query = \Logs::with(
                        array(
                                'client',
                                'details' => function($qry)
                                 {
                                    $qry->with('notes');
                                },
                                'user' => function($qry)
                                {
                                    $qry->With('employee');
                                },
                                'product'
                                )
                            );

return $query->get();
```

But if I limit

```
return $query->take(12000)->get();
```

It will work just that i need the remaining data as well.

Based from my research, the problem is the server memory usage, it is currently running at a constant 3GB out of 16GB RAM, will be moving it to our main server that has 64GB RAM.

I also have added

```
    set_time_limit (10000);

    ini_set('memory_limit','-1');
```

Any suggestion how to tackle this kind of problem?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use nested eager loading, i.e.:

```
$query = \Log::with('client', 'details.notes', 'user.employee', 'product')->get();
```

Comment: i need the details and the notes, nevertheless that is not really the problem. the problem is that the query is returning empty result.

Comment: Using ```details.notes``` will fetch the ```details``` related models on your ```Log``` model *and* the ```notes``` related models on the ```details``` model. Try my query, with ```->limit(1)``` to see if it is memory related.